# Macbook Air A1465 - Not Booting - Cannot power off

Tags: macbook-pro

I have a Macbook Air A1465 that was having some issues with Teamviewer, so I used the terminal to remove all teamviewer files with the following command

`for x in $(mdfind -name "teamviewer"); do rm $x; done`

Now on startup, all I get is a black screen with the loading spinner, but **I can't power off the Mac by holding the power button for 10 seconds.**
The mouse cursor flashes up every now and then, but that's the only sign of life apart from the spinner.

Is there any other way to power off the Macbook besides waiting for the battery to run dry?

Comment: hold power button for 10 seconds

Comment: I can't power off the Mac by holding the power button.

Comment: take out the battery :) or wait 8 hours

Comment: I would rather not disassemble the Macbook if there's another option...however that is my last resort at the moment, if I can get my hands on some pentalobe screwdrivers, and I'd rather not have to wait 8 hours if I power it off and back on and it does the same thing again...hence the "other way to power it off besides waiting for the battery to run dry"